# Windows Community Toolkit AttachedCardShadow and AttachedDropShadow is not working

Tags: uno-platform, windows-community-toolkit

When using the attachedDropShadow, it builds and runs with no errors, but the shadows dont work.

When using the AttachedCardShadow, it doesnt build and complains about the type being not found.

> > The type {using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media}AttachedCardShadow could not be found

Any ideas?

I tried using the shadows from the Windows Community Toolkit instead of the ElevatedView in UNO.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the types in the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media namespace are not implemented for Uno. You can find the source code for these classes in the [Uno GitHub repository](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/ef3f52364801bc20be98677ef77d7b205b23f2e0/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media), but when you look at the [project file](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/ef3f52364801bc20be98677ef77d7b205b23f2e0/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media.csproj) you will see that most of those classes have been removed from compilation, so they won't be found when you install the Uno.CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media NuGet package.

I believe the reason for this is because there is a dependency on Win2D, at least for the [AttachedCardShadow](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/ef3f52364801bc20be98677ef77d7b205b23f2e0/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media/Shadows/AttachedCardShadow.cs). Unfortunately, [per this discussion](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/discussions/11613), Win2D is not yet supported for all platforms supported by Uno. I suspect this is because Win2D is relying on more Windows native graphics API calls. I only dug down as deep as perusing the C++ files for Win2D, specifically the [CanvasGeometry class](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D/blob/e63db04e358855beb33a6d4c78aef11c6a733bee/winrt/lib/geometry/CanvasGeometry.cpp) that is required by AttachedCardShadow. But I'm a high-level C# dev, not a C++ Windows dev, so that's as far as I've managed to go so far.

So the upshot is that for now, AttachedCardShadow relies on native Windows graphics calls, which Uno has not yet gotten around to supporting in their non-Windows platforms. Therefore, these classes appear to have been removed from the Uno.CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Media NuGet package altogether.